# Finding every CKrecords recordID - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

I'm having trouble finding a recordName String that will find any CKRecord depending on the user. I want to fetch the record, modify it, and then save it back to the cloud. I can do this but with only one record at a time. If i switch users my project crashes because the recordName: doesn't work for the new user.

```
    if userLoad() {
    let newInfo = CKRecordID(recordName: "212F4229-67B3-469D-AF4A-B9A693512AD2")
        database.fetch(withRecordID: newInfo) { (record, Error) in
            record?["username"] = self.textField1.text as CKRecordValue?
            record?["type"] = self.textField2.text as CKRecordValue?
            record?["hours"] = self.textField3.text as CKRecordValue?


            self.database.save(record!, completionHandler: { (record, error) in
                if error != nil{print("error on info")
                } else {print("saved new info")}
            })
        }} else {print("no user")}

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "account4", sender: self)

}
```

Comment: Why do you care about record ids?  You would typically use a query to find all of the records you are interested in, based on some search criteria.

Comment: I am returning the CKRecord fields to a UIViewTable that displays the current Users information. Each CKRecord has its own recordID, so when I switch users the recordID I used for the previous User doesn't work for the new one. I'm wondering if there's a string that will grab the Users CKRecord no matter what User I am logged into. You know?

Comment: I still don't know why you need to know anything about record IDs in the situation you have described.  You simply pass the `CKRecord` object to the next view controller or whatever.  To find the record for the user that is logged in (assuming you are using the public CloudKit area and not a private area) then you will need to store the user identifier in the record so that you can query for it.

Comment: What is the definition of what you so-call the user?  Does your app know what it is?

Comment: Yes I am using a private database. I need the recordID so I can fetch the CKRecord fields that contains the Users information on it, I can then make changes to those fields, and then save that record back to the record type.  -Paulw11

Comment: I have saved the "users" to NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore(), in the userLoad() function. The app can tell when I am signed in and not - El tomato

Comment: I still don’t know why you need to know the record Id, especially if you are using a private database. The only records that are available to the current user are that user’s records.

Comment: Can you fetch a record, change the information in the fields, and save it back to the record type by using a query?

Comment: "Yes I am using a private database."  You have made your question more puzzling.

Comment: I use a private database so different users can't see other users information(CKRecords). Is there a string that fetches the Users CKRecord no matter what User is logged in?